# akamai pipeline save cannot write to dist

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, pipeline, iterm, akamai

I am using akamai CLI with MacOS and iTerm.

I am trying to execute `akamai pipeline save -p myProject test`. It returns a
`Unexpected error occurred:  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open...`
error and does NOT create a dist folder.

I suspect something to do with iTerm not having write permission. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by manually creating the `dist` folder once before running the command. That worked.